# Android Libgdx: draw a lot of sprites

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

I want to draw a lot of sprites so I wrote this code in render method:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    spriteBlocchi[i] = new Sprite(blocco);
    batch.draw(spriteBlocchi[i],xBlocco,50,100,200);
    xBlocco = xBlocco + 0.1f;
}
```

`spriteBlocchi`is a Sprite array. I wrote this because in this way all 100 sprites are drawn by the render method, but it doesn't work. It draws only a sprite and I don't know why, in fact I created an array of sprites. This cycle is always called in render, so all the blocks should be drawn...what's the problem?

Comment: don't create your sprite array inside render, create it once outside your render method. 0.1f for the x coord diff is not much. For 100 sprites, that is a difference of what, 10 pixels? Are you just drawing 100 images mostly on top of each other?

Comment: @PeterR I solved it. I had to reset xBlocco each time.

Comment: @PeterR but why not in render? I have to update it always

Comment: I meant "new" inside the render can lead to performance issues. Creating 100 new sprites 30-80 times a second is a lot. Create your sprites on say screen create or "up front", and then in render or update determine which sprite to show at what position. But don't create new sprites every second.

Comment: Also, when drawing them this way (`batch.draw()`), you should use TextureRegion. Sprite is a very bloated version of TextureRegion that includes a bunch of parameters that you aren't using. With TextureRegion, you can use a single instance and draw it many times.